# How can I pass the value of a `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` after the event `submit` button?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

In the code bellow, `arrayStored`is not define in the `submit`function. I try to get the `arrayStored` value trough the `e.parameter`method (didn't work). I'm new to `HtmlService` and I'm reading the documentation. How can I pass the value of a `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` after the event `submit`button? Do I have to create a `HTML`file to store it there?

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
    var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
    var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
      if (thesesType != ''){
         var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
         arrayList.push(newArray);
         break;
         }
      }
   }
  arrayList.sort();
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(550).setHeight(450);
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
                   .setId('panel');
    var label = app.createLabel("Selecione os itens desejados").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
    app.add(label);
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){      
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
   }
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
   panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);  
  var arrayListString =  JSON.stringify(arrayList);
  var arrayStored = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
  arrayStored.setContent(arrayListString);
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);
  mydoc.show(app);
}

function submit(e){
  var savedArray = arrayStored.getContent();
  Logger.log("savedArray #2 = " + savedArray);
  // continues...
}

function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) // if we find a match, return true
            return true;    }
    return false; // if we got here, there was no match, so return false
 }
```

Comment: Your question is too fuzzy. What is need of HtmlService.createHtmlOutput() in your code? After seeing your current code, it  doesn't seem necessary to use HtmlService.

Comment: Is this a Stand Alone App, or in a spreadsheet, or Doc?

Comment: What would you use instead? I`m trying to pass to a server function a string which doesn't fit in userProperties.

Comment: This is a spreadsheet, @SandyGood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in HtmlService to pass parameters to a server function you need to call `google.script.run.functionName(parameters)` in the HTML file

in summary, you need to bind a function to the Submit button using javascript using a `<script>`tag. That function will gather all the form data and pass it as an argument in the `google.script.run.functionName(parameters)` call

Also, looks like you are mixing HtmlService and UiService. The later has been deprecated last month and can stop working any time now. The advise is to build your sidebar entirely on an HTML file.

Edit: Since I did not understand what exactly you are trying to do in your code, here goes a simple exemple:

you code.gs file

```
function showSidebar() { // this is used to show the sidebar in the document
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar') //sidebar is the name of your HTML file
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
};

function doSomething(txt) { //that is the function called in your html file
  Logger.log('Input text: '+ txt);
};
```

in you HTML file. Say you call it 'sidebar'

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="sample" id="sample">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="callServer()">
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   function callServer() { //this is the function called when pressing the submit button
     var text = $('#sample').val();
     google.script.run.doSomething(text); //this will call the doSomething() server function with the argument text
   };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @filipeglfw! Yes, I`m mixing HtmlService with UiService. Could you provide some sample code in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an HTML Object that can be returned, but I don't see that the code is serving it to the browser.  Usually, HTML content is served to the browser in the `doGet()` function:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}
```

The code created an HTML Output object:

```
var arrayStored = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
```

Then you set some content:

```
arrayStored.setContent(arrayListString);
```

But I don't see that it ever gets returned (Sent to the browser).

Comment: How could I do that in a spreadsheet app? (and not in a standalone one)

Comment: Do you want a sidebar, (HTML on the right side of the screen that is always present) or HTML in a Dialog Box. (A pop up box in the middle of the spreadsheet that the user closes after the are done)

Comment: A think a dialog box would be the solution most similar to the UI implementation.